# how to install traceroute

Tags: traceroute

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
net-tools is already the newest version (1.60-26ubuntu1).
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  traceroute
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 279 not upgraded.
Need to get 46.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 172 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 traceroute i386 1:2.0.21-1
  Could not connect to 172.16.0.1:8888 (172.16.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/traceroute/traceroute_2.0.21-1_i386.deb  Could not connect to 172.16.0.1:8888 (172.16.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Hint `apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

Answer (score 2):

To install the `traceroute` package, enter the following at the command-line:

```
sudo apt install traceroute
```

That worked fine for me. If it does not work for you, check if you have a network problem and make sure other things are updated first, like this:

```
sudo apt update
```

followed by

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

and then after that, try installing traceroute again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a proxy or a firewall?
For me it seems that you enter the correct `apt install ....` code but the connection itself is not being established.